# Can we avoid static data in ejb proxy object?

Tags: java, spring, ejb, ejb-3.1, ejb-2.x

Can we avoid the static data ref. in the EJB proxy object that we get at the client using rmi call.

I am using the spring Di for getting ejb object and can see lots of Static ref. in my object.

Also i am calling from local only but doing a remote call.

I have checked for the same on the net but not found much. can anyone advice here..

Thanks in advance !!! :)

Comment: What do you mean by "static data ref"?  Can you show some example?  What problem is it causing?  Why is local vs remote relevant?

Comment: I ma having application where same code is behaving differently here. Both the application use slsb in my application it destroy/remove ejb from container once call is over and in another application it is not removing it. I have checked the pool mechaniah and configurations of both the application but all is same but in debuging the object values set in my application shows static ref. Which are not seen in the same code in other app. So wanted to avoid static variable to see if the ejb container allows to pool the bean insted of removing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: EJB proxies are container-generated remote proxies, you should interact with their interfaces, not their implementations.  The actual implementation is vendor-specific, server-generated code which deals with all the complexity of EJB services.  It should only be of interest if you want to know how the container itself works.

On using remote interfaces:  It's fine to use remote connections to EJBs which are in fact hosted locally.  This makes your application more extensible, as it doesn't make local hosting a dependency.  It does add an overhead to calls, so there is a performance cost to this, but it's not that large.